# Coming to Scala from Java, should I use List or Buffer as a replacement for ArrayList

Tags: java, list, scala, buffer

Hi all a little background: I was taught Java through college and have been using Java for some time. Now, we are moving our entire Java Project to Scala.

I am used to using `ArrayList`s and I know the Scala to Java conversion is, `Buffer` is equivalent to `List`. I am a little confused though, if my project is purely Scala should I still be using `Buffer`? I understand `List` is essentially a `LinkedList` in `Scala`.

Comment: I suggest reading [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html).

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayBuffer` is indeed the Scala  equivalent of `ArrayList`. Although you are free to use it as a replacement, I would advice against it.

In Scala, the programming paradigm is often different, leaning towards immutable structures and functional transformations on them. When you leverage the rich Scala collections library methods, you can usually do without mutable collections entirely.

**I usually end up using `Seq` or `IndexedSeq` when I need efficient random access.** Their default implementations `List` created by `Seq()` and `Vector` created `IndexedSeq()` are usually sufficient.

---

To give you an example - in Java, you may often want to use `ArrayList` to store some temporary results like this:

```
public static List<String> readNames(File file) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (line.startsWith("NAME: ")) {
            lines.add(line.split(":")[1]);
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

but in Scala, this may look like this:

```
def readNames(file: File): Seq[String] =
  Source.fromFile(file)
    .getLines()
    .filter(_.startsWith("NAME: "))
    .map(_.split(":")(1))
    .toSeq
```

You can see that you just describe the transformation in a declarative way and do not need a mutable collection for temporary results. (Such collections may be created internally by the library functions, but you  are shielded from that).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in Scala, I use typically 2 collections: `Seq`, and `List`. I get to force `List` (subclass of `Seq`) when I want to forbid the use of `Streams`, which are lazy and may lead to strange errors.

Most of the times you will don't care a lot about the difference, and you will return a simple `Seq`, and your code will not even have problems if you change between `Seq` and `List`